# Handle URLs for model entries only

Tags: python, django

Given a simple model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    blogname = = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)

class BlogEntry(models.Model):
    blogname = models.ForeignKey('Blog')
    # more blog related fields 
    ...
```

and say the following blogs `linux`, `python` and `other` how would you handle the URLs to the respective blog pages pages. Currently I have set up a view to list all the blogs for the model `Blog` as the root page:

```
url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index')
```

The question is how to map the blog `linux` to `/linux` the way I am handling this currently is:

```
url(r'(?P<blog_name>.*)/','blog.views.blog_page')
```

but of course that means `/.*` is a valid URL and I only want `/linux`,`/python` and `/other`.

Comment: You want all words? `url(r'(?P<blog_name>\w+/','blog.views.blog_page')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reject other values of `blog_name` with a [`Http404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception).

Comment: You can use the [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/) helper to implement Ignacio's suggestion.